How to place a single item on a responsive grid row?
I am using a grid to place cards. The grid is responsive using minimax and auto-fit:
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));

But, I would like to have a single card in the first row, such that the card does not span (i.e. it is the same width as the cards in the following rows).
So, here are the desired layouts for 1-3 columns (depending on screen width) where x means "card" and . means "empty space":
x
x
x

x .
x x
x x

x . .
x x x
x x x
x x x

I have tried specifying grid-row for the 2nd card onward but since I do not know in advance how many columns there will be (responsive grid template), I do not know.
I would need a property like min-grid-row.
EDIT:

I cannot place the first item outside the grid because I want all cards to have the same width (responsive)


May be I am missing something, but looks like setting grid-column: 1 for the second element is enough:


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: .5em;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 1;
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item">Item 11</div>
  <div class="item">Item 12</div>
</div>




works, fantastic answer! FYI, by a similar reasoning I had tried and failed to use grid-row: 2 and didn't think of setting grid column to 1. What surprises me is that it seems to be a true "line break" i.e. affects subsequent items even without setting order. Thank you!

that's what I have tried initially but it didn't work for me, not sure why (and I was convinced it would work)

Unless you are using grid-auto-flow: dense, once you have placed an element on the second row, the empty spaces in the first row will not be used.

You can get close by placing a pseudo-element in row 1 (here colored blue) that spans to the end column (with a min-width matching you min-column width).
Then at the smallest width (say) mobile, you disable the pseudo-element in a media query.
https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bGPbBNr


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: .5em;
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
  min-width: 250px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 520px) {
  .grid::after {
    background: pink;
    content: none;
  }
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="item">Item 10</div>
  <div class="item">Item 11</div>
  <div class="item">Item 12</div>
</div>




looks good, will accept later today unless something else comes along. Thanks!

turns out there is an even better answer using grid-column: 1 on second child, see accepted answer.
